# Artikel in "Währung der Länder", wenn es doch das Land/die Länder heißt

Tags: grammatical-case, article

Im [Wörterbuch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Waehrung) steht zu *die Währung* als Bedeutungserklärung "gesetzliches Zahlungsmittel eines Landes oder der Länder einer Währungsunion".

Wenn man davon ausgeht, dass der Plural von Land Länder ist, warum hat in der Bedeutungserklärung *Länder* den Artikel *der*?

Als der avgJoe beschreibt hat, ist es **der** wegen des Genitivs. Wenn mann nur ein Zahlungsmittel möglichkeit schreibt, sieht es mann deutlicher: gesetzliches Zahlungsmittel der Länder einer Währungsunion.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel

Comment: @MaxMuster: Das hilft nur jenen, die ohnehin schon die richtige Antwort wissen. Wenn man eine Fremdsprache lernt, und nicht weiß, welcher Fall der richtige ist, weiß man auch nicht, welche Frage die richtige ist. Wenn ich glaube, es müsse z.B. »den Länder« heißen, dann halte ich die Frage »wem« für ähnlich richtig oder falsch wie die Frage »wessen«. Und »Comprende« hilft auch genau niemandem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Pronomen ändert sich aufgrund des [Genitivs](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel). Im Genitiv wird aus dem Pronomen "die" in der Mehrzahl ein "der".

English Translation:
This is due to the "[Genitiv](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel)". In the "Genitiv" the pronoun used with the plural of the noun becomes "der" instead of "die". This is a grammar concept called the cases and is worth studying. For a fun explanation, see [this resource from the University of Texas.](https://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/cas_01.html)

Comment: Da die Frage auf Deutsch ist, formuliere doch bitte auch eine deutsche Antwort.

Comment: @infinitezero I updated my response with a brief German translation. I hope it is correct.

Comment: Wenn eine Frage auf deutsch gestellt wird, sollten nicht nur alle Antworten, sondern auch alle Kommentare in derselben Sprache verfasst werden. Dies ist ein Deutsch-Forum. Es kann nicht vorausgesetzt werden, dass der Fragesteller Englisch spricht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Verstanden.